# Make navigation drawer toggle like new GApps

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

How can I make the navigation drawer look like the one of the new materialized GApps?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

Comment: This is the right one, but I don't get it working :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476837/android-5-0-material-design-style-navigation-drawer-for-kitkat/27664931#27664931