# Android lollipop Menu button to Back button rendering

Tags: android, eclipse, image, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

If you see the `Google Play` app , when swiping the menu the `menu button` convert itself to `back button` with the finger gradually and nicely, it seems not an animation. can any one help me to achieve this thing ?
Feel free to move/close the post but please be nice to redirect me in any helpful direction.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: just create a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) using the new Toolbar widget and it takes care of everything. Just make the navdrawer appear below the toolbar, [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476837/android-5-0-material-design-style-navigation-drawer-for-kitkat)

Comment: thanks, checking that

Answer (score 0):

Icon transitions can be implemented using AnimatedStateListDrawable (There’s also support for animated vector icons.)

e.g.

```
 public void setOrAnimatePlusCheckIcon(final ImageView imageView, boolean isCheck,
                                      boolean allowAnimate) {
    if (!hasL()) {
        compatSetOrAnimatePlusCheckIcon(imageView, isCheck, allowAnimate);
        return;
    }

    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (!(drawable instanceof AnimatedStateListDrawable)) {
        drawable = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_schedule_fab_icon_anim);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
    imageView.setColorFilter(isCheck ?
            mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_accent_1) : Color.WHITE);
    if (allowAnimate) {
        imageView.setImageState(isCheck ? STATE_UNCHECKED : STATE_CHECKED, false);
        drawable.jumpToCurrentState();
        imageView.setImageState(isCheck ? STATE_CHECKED : STATE_UNCHECKED, false);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageState(isCheck ? STATE_CHECKED : STATE_UNCHECKED, false);
        drawable.jumpToCurrentState();
    }
}
```

code from https://github.com/google/iosched