# Actionbar Sherlock How to change drawer icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can i change the position of the drawer icon and rotate it when open the drawer and change it to arrow back. like on the google store.

http://s23.postimg.org/5olnsi3gr/google_play_5_1_2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionBar that you showed in your link is the default **Lollipop** ActionBar. In order to use it, you should use the **support v7 appcompat** library, that way it can be used with pre-Lollipop devices aswell. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7).

Some useful links to get you going

- [Android developers tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)
- [Another tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use toolbar in your project.

Just go through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476837/android-5-0-material-design-style-navigation-drawer-for-kitkat) : Hope it will help you.!!!

Comment: You do not need to use the Toolbar in order to use the drawer toggle. You can, but it can work without it too.