# Material design navigation drawer not sliding out

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I followed this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476837/android-5-0-material-design-style-navigation-drawer-for-kitkat)'s instructions and managed to get the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and its animation working. However, no navigation drawer slides out. Why is that?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:primaryColor="#33B5E5"
    app:accentColor="#FFFFFF" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:name="com.wsandhu.conjugation.DrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code in the `onCreate()` method in **MainActivity.java**:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        });
    }

...

}
```

I have a `DrawerFragment` class and its XML file, but as I said, nothing slides out when I tap the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in my app. The toggle animates perfectly.

The five methods that needed to be overrided as stated in the other post are in my `MainActivity`, after the `onCreate()` method. I really don't know what else to add, I can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand `DrawerLayout`, in part due to [jpardogo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1787135/jpardogo) answer.

I needed to set the proper main content frame in my activity's XML file, so I made `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` the root element of the file, and put my activity's `LinearLayout` above the navigation drawer `fragment` element. Here is the proper, working code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Main layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
        android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:primaryColor="#33B5E5"
        app:accentColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Nav drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:name="com.wsandhu.conjugation.DrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It would help to compare this to the XML file in the original post. Hope this helps.