# ActionBarDrawerToggle icon missing when using AppCompat v22

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm using Appcompat v22 to use tinted style for AutoCompleteTextView. 
However, as soon as I changed my build.gradle from this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
```

The ActionBarDrawerToggle Icon (Hamburger icon) goes missing. (However, if I slide from left, the drawer gets revealed)

Inside onCreate():

```
    mDrawerLayout = (BBDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            trackEvent(TrackingAware.MENU_SHOWN, null);
            toolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Have also called syncState()

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mDrawerToggle != null) {
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (mDrawerToggle != null) {
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

If I downgrade the appcompat version back to 21.0.3, everything starts to work.

Comment: When you say "everything starts to work", are you talking about the icon?

Comment: yes, then the icon becomes visible in the toolbar.

Comment: Same here, WTF Google??? DOCUMENT IT!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The relevant part is in the last line of code, I have them in my `Activity.onCreate(..)` method:

```
    _drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 0, 0);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

As I remember that line is documented too but in appcompat v21 they were ignored (or at least the default was different..)

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  The only thing that seems to make the home button show up is calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true).  When I do that, I see the hamburger icon, and when I click it, it acts as the back button.   I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve it for me.  I'm already calling: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: Figured it out, I was using v4 AppCompat ActionBarDrawerToggle which is deprecated, I upgraded to v7 and it works now

Answer (score 5):

For those encountering the same problem as Dapp (toggle showing back arrow instead of hamburger icon), this is most likely because you're missing a `drawerToggle.syncState()` in your Activity.

To be more specific, you have to override the onPostCreate() method like this :

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

This isn't the only method that needs to be overriden. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551298/4917907) by jpardogo for more details.

Answer (score 0):

also be sure to use the right theme on your actionbar...if your actionbar is dark, the default icon might be black unless you do this:
"@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

It bit me, but only on Android 4.x devices (5.x+ worked fine oddly enough)