# Android 5 Hamburger doen't open the drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to make a simple navigation drawer, matching the material guidelines. I'm following along [the official training](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Everything is running well, only a tap on the hamburger icon won't open the drawer. I can open the drawer with a swipe from the side, only the hamburger isn't working. I already looked up some other questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476837/android-5-0-material-design-style-navigation-drawer-for-kitkat), but nothing helped.  What did I miss?

Here is my code:

Activity.java:

```
public class stream extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String[] mDrawerTitles;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream);

    // Init the Support-toolbar
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START|Gravity.LEFT)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.square7.gtz.lwenzahn.stream"
 android:background="@color/ColorBackground">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content View -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"/>

    <!-- Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:elevation="8dp" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: In `Android Studio`: File -> New Project -> Navigation Drawer. It implements it for you.

Comment: How did a hamburger get involved in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the DrawerLayout as the root layout of the activity. You are almost there but you see how you use the RelativeLayout as the root (or at least that is what I infer from the posted xml - the RelativeLayout does not look like it has a closing tag so maybe you just missed it)?

The NavigationDrawer opens on the tap of the "hamburger" (or icon) only when it is the root so that Android knows that the DrawerLayout is encompassing everything. My guess is the toolbar you are including is interfering with the layout.