# Where add ImageView on the top of navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I followed this tutorial from CodePath to create the navigation drawer in android: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer.

What i want to achieve is to add the image view above of the list view, i tried different solution but none works.

this is the activity_main.xml

```
   <my.custom.package.path.FragmentNavigationDrawer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
      android:layout_width="240dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
      </my.custom.package.path.FragmentNavigationDrawer>
```

This is the drawer_nav_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the final result is this one:

[image: Navigation drawer]

What i want to achieve is that:

[image: Navigationd]
But only the background image on the top.

Can someone please help me?

Best

Brus

Comment: If you want static image above list use answer of @VjLxmi else create custom layout and add as header view to listview.

Answer (score 2):

```
<my.custom.package.path.FragmentNavigationDrawer
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="240dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <!--Place your ImageView here-->
     <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

     <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
      android:layout_width="240dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"     
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
 </LinearLayout>
</my.custom.package.path.FragmentNavigationDrawer>
```

Place the ImageView Above the Listview within LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the Material Design style nav drawer, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664931/4764088